# Embed network IP in powershell gui

Tags: powershell, string-interpolation

I am currently working on a powershell application using windows forms inside powershell.
Building the forms is simple enough and I am familiar, however I have an issue that some commands that work in powershell seem to not work when putting it into my form.
For example I am attempting to list the Network IP of a computer as the text of a label.
The code is:

```
$IPAddress = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Where-Object {$_.Ipaddress.length -gt 1} 
$netIP = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$netIP.Text = "Network IP: $IPAddress.ipaddress[0]"
$netIP.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(0,45)
$netIP.AutoSize = $true
$mainForm.Controls.Add($netIP)
```

Namely these work perfectly outside the form:

```
$IPAddress = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Where-Object {$_.Ipaddress.length -gt 1}
    Write-Host "Network IP:" $IPAddress.ipaddress[0]
```

The command itself works perfectly in Powershell but when I put it in the form as the label text it gives me the output of:

> \\computername\root\cimv2:Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration.Index=11.ipaddress(0)

Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for any assistance

-Tairros

Comment: for your first issue, references to a member/property of an object need to be wrapped in a *subexpression* operator `$(...)` when in a string. So, it should be: `$netIP.Text = "Network IP: $($IPAddress.ipaddress[0])"`.

Comment: It's always the basics that come bite you in the butt.
Thank you very much! That fixed the first issue perfectly.

Comment: @Tairros, in the interest of having questions focused on just one problem, please create a _new_ question post for your second question.

Comment: @mklement0
Will do then.